# Play a protected video content in iOS using AVPlayer

Tags: ios, swift, avplayer, protected, http-live-streaming

im trying to play a protected video which you need to be logged thru our API and get a cookie to access to the m3u8. In Safari, i need to be logged in in order to play the video. I tried to implement this but doesnt work at all.

```
                let cookies: [Any] = HTTPCookieStorage.shared.cookies!
                self.playerAsset = AVURLAsset.init(url: urlStream!, options:[AVURLAssetHTTPCookiesKey : cookies])
                let item = AVPlayerItem(asset: self.playerAsset!)
                self.playerItems.append(item)
```

Anyone could help me ?

Answer (score -1):

could you play the video in saffari? If yes then you can use the new safari webview instead of avplayer

Comment: i'm using Alamofire to connect to the API to access to our playlist and i think i need to get this cookie to put there. It doesnt work in Safari if i don't have the cookie...